# Como agregar un icono a un DataGrid que se llena mediante una consulta SQL, arroja error System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2015, vb, datagridview

Buen día comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema, quiero agregar un icono de + a un datagrid que se llena mediante una consulta sql. El problema es que cuando lo quiero llenar con lo que busque en la pagina me arroja el siguiente error
[image: Error]

Adjunto el codigo donde intento cargar la imagen, aclaro que las columnas Contador y Suma son agregadas dentro del mismo Select de la siguiente manera Select SPACE(20) as Contador, SPACE(20) as Suma, sigue la consulta.. El codigo VB es el siguiente

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellFormatting
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim n As Integer
        n = dgv1.RowCount - 1
        For i = 0 To n
            dgv1.Item(1, i).Value = New Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\img\image.bmp"))
        Next
End Sub
```

Bueno, espero que me puedan ayudar ya que he probado de todo y no consigo dar en la tecla con esto. Se que si las columnas fueran agregadas manualmente seria mas facil hacerlo, pero toda la info es traida de una base de datos sql. Aguardo sus comentarios. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Saludos. No es error; lo que pone es el nombre de la clase del objeto. Hace falta el código de esa tabla; básicamente te hace falta poner el componente en el cual se pueda mostrar el contenido de lo que cargar como `New Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\img\image.bmp"))`; está en inglés pero espero te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564978/displaying-image-in-datagridviewimagecolumn-in-vb-net/16565923

Comment: Es que de esa manera agrego una columna de forma manual, y todas las columnas que levanta el datagrid vienen de un datasource. Hay manera de combinar columnas que se agregan a mano con otras que levanta una query? Porque eso que me pasaste lo he visto, pero funciona solo agregando la columna manualmente.

Comment: Espero te sean de utilidad http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-image.htm y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365965/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-my-datagridviewimagecolumn

Comment: Roberto, probe generar el recurso con la imagen y despues meterla en el codigo de la siguiente manera 
```
For i = 0 To n
                dgv1.Item(1, i).Value = My.Resources.Image1
            Next
```
 pero me sigue tirando la misma frase en toda la columna. Te agradezco igual por la ayuda pero sigo sin poder hacerlo.

Comment: A continuación en VB Agregar Imagen al a Data GridView (http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_image.htm) el problema es que estas asignando como valor  el objeto imagen. Lo que necesitas es cambiar el tipo a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

Comment: Claro Roberto, el tema de ese ejemplo es que las columnas estan creadas manualmente y es justamente lo que no hago en mi proyecto, ya que las columnas del datagrid se generan mediante una consulta sql, es por esto que no se como agregar una columna de imagen y combinarla con las columnas sql. Me esta faltando esa informacion.